# SVG Mask Does Not Render at all

Tags: css, svg

How do I make a circle in a rectangle by using SVG mask?

This is my progress so far: https://jsfiddle.net/veyxp531/

```
<div>
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 700" style="outline:1px solid red; width: 100%;">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask" x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" fill="#000"/>
                <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
     
       <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent"></circle>
   
       <rect x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.2"/></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I tried to make a circle inside a rectangle, but apparently the svg mask inside my codes does not render properly.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

- whatever outside of the circle should be leave blank, half opacity
- whatever inside of the circle should be contrast,
- the circle in the centre should be larger than the rectangle.

Any helps should be appreciated !

Comment: black becomes transparent, white stays solid. Here both your circle and rect are black -> all is transparent.

Comment: I have changed the fill of the rectangle inside the mask as well as the rect outside of the mask to '#000' but nothing happened.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/f9ec5bf6e84013451438238bded07558?editors=1000

Comment: Thanks, the inner circle is not transparent. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it.  The simplest is probably just to place a translucent white rectangle over the image. Then cut a circle out of that white rectangle.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 700" style="outline:1px solid red; width: 100%;">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" fill="#000" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <image x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400"
         xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/800/400"/>

  <rect x="100" y="100" width="800" height="400" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0.5" mask="url(#mask)" />
  <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```